# is there any way to remove the submit button from a GET request?

Tags: php, forms

I have a page that views `photos`, each `photo` is in an `album`.

At the top of the page I have an `albums` select box with the `album_id` and `album_name` respectively.

```
<form action="change-album.php" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Select Album</label></td>
            <td><select name="album_id"><?=$albums_str?></select></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="change-album" value="Select Album" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The default is `uncategorised photos` on page load, and then the user can select their album and press `submit`, which returns the photos from that album.

Originally this form used POST.

However, if a user selects an `album`, AND THEN clicks a `photo`. They will see a large version of the photo. But if a user presses BACK on the browser, it says `FORM MUST BE RE-SENT`. And this is because the last request on that page posted the `album_id` to fetch the photos.

I decided the use GET. Therefore when the user goes `BACK` to that page, the `album_id` is in the query string! No form re-send! YAAY!

However, Obviously using GET will also send the submit button in the querystring!

So I end up getting:

```
localhost/admin/view-photos?album_id=1&change-album=Select+Album
```

Is there anyway I can remove this from the query string?

Or can anybody think of a better way to achieve this?

I want to remove it from the query string because it doesn't really need to be there. its useless

Comment: You can use POST, but your script should produce no output and redirect to another page for display. This will not give you the Re-submit Form notice as the page that the form was submitted to was not cached and wont appear in the history

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove the submit button from the request array if you remove the `name` attribute of the button `<input>`.

So in your case, you will have to modify the following:

```
<input type="submit" name="change-album" value="Select Album" />
```

To be the one below instead:

```
<input type="submit" value="Select Album" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the name attribute:

```
<input type="submit" value="Select Album" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When a form is submitted, it is converted into key-value pairs, so if there is no name, or no value the element is not sent:

```
<form action="change-album.php" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Select Album</label></td>
            <td><select name="album_id"><?=$albums_str?></select></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Select Album" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the button's name anywhere in the script then just don't give the submit button a name attribute.

```
<input type="submit" value="Select Album" />
```

If you do need it for some part of your script but want to discard it so it doesn't get stored in the database when you're done with it, then just unset it.

```
unset ($_GET ['change-album']);
```